# pythonでnot enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)というエラーが出ます

Tags: python

pythonで画像の二値化をしたく、いろいろと調べて作成しているのですが、

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
３３行目の`(b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)`がエラー部分みたいです。
変数と要素の数が一致しないみたいなのですが、解決できませんでした。
教えてくださる方がおられましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import cv2
import pathlib
import os
import datetime
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

input_dir = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/images4'  
output_dir = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/edited/'  

database_name = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/main.db4' 

conn = sqlite3.connect (database_name)
cur = conn. cursor ()
cur. execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item")

cur. execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
     time TEXT, 
     white FLOAT, 
     black FLOAT
)""")

image_list = list(pathlib.Path(input_dir).glob('*.JPG'))

for i in range(len(image_list)):

 img = cv2.imread(str(image_list[i]), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

 fsrc = np.array (img, dtype=np. float32) / 255
 (b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)
 gray = 2 * g - b - r
 (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2. minMaxLoc (gray)

 gray_u8 = np.array( (gray - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) * 255, dtype=np.uint8)
 (thresh, img_th) = cv2. threshold (gray_u8, -1.0, 255, cv2. THRESH_OTSU)
 

 img_name = os.path.basename(image_list[i])
 cv2.imwrite(output_dir + img_name, img_th)

 
 cnt_white = cv2. countNonZero (img_th)
 cnt_black = img_th.size - cnt_white
 #print("全体の画素数：" ,img_th.size) 
 print("白の画素数：" ,cnt_white)
 #print("黒の画素数：" ,cnt_black)

 now = datetime.datetime.now()

#データベース
 data = (now, cnt_white, cnt_black)
 cur. execute("INSERT INTO item (time, white, black) values (?, ?, ?)", data)

 conn. commit ()

conn. close ()
```

Comment: 画像データが元からモノクロであるか、`fsrc = np.array (img, dtype=np. float32) / 255`の処理でモノクロにしてしまったのではありませんか？

Comment: ご解答ありがとうございます。元画像はカラー画像で、読み込みもカラーのままできているのではと思っております。　この処理については調べて作成したものなのですが、どのように変更すればカラーのまま次の処理に移れるか分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: 「この処理については調べて作成したもの」とのことですが、”何をしたくて”書いたコードなのでしょうか？やりたい事とコードが合っていないのかもしれません。

Comment: 問題を再現出来るサンプルの画像データを1つだけでも質問に追記(アップロード)してみてはどうでしょう？ プログラム部分も問題を再現出来る分だけに縮めるとか。 こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @merino この処理に関しましては、二値化の際にG成分を強調させるExG処理というものを行いたく書いたものになります。

Answer (score 0):

> ３３行目の`(b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)`がエラー部分みたいです。

実行中のどこかで 間違いが入ってるのでしょう
たぶんその位置でのエラーは発生しないかも
RGB, GrayScale, (100,100,1) などの画像データも正しく処理できるようです

この回答では, データの確認方法も示しているので, 画像データや NumPy ndarrayの内容を 一度確認するとよいかも

---

ランダムな画像データを元に再現してみると
`size=(100,100,2)` の行を有効にするとエラーが発生します

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
img = rng.integers(256, size=(100,100,3))
# img = rng.integers(256, size=(100,100,2))

# 以下は質問のソースコードから
import cv2
fsrc = np.array (img, dtype=np. float32) / 255
(b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)
gray = 2 * g - b - r
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2. minMaxLoc (gray)

gray_u8 = np.array( (gray - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) * 255, dtype=np.uint8)
(thresh, img_th) = cv2. threshold (gray_u8, -1.0, 255, cv2. THRESH_OTSU)
```

colabでの実行結果 (`size=(100,100,2)` の行を有効にした場合)
3つのデータが必要なところ, 2つしか与えられていない, ということ
(`size`の指定の最後が `2`だから)

```py
      6 import cv2
      7 fsrc = np.array (img, dtype=np. float32) / 255
----> 8 (b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)
      9 gray = 2 * g - b - r
     10 (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2. minMaxLoc (gray)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

---

また以下の画像データで検証してみると
GRAYSCALEの画像であっても `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`を指定すると この場合 `(512, 512, 3)`になるので, エラーが出ることはないはず

```py
orgf = 'sample_data/lena.png'
grayf = 'sample_data/lena_gray.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(orgf)
print('imread \t\t', img.shape)
# imread         (512, 512, 3)

im_gray = cv2.imread(orgf, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imwrite(grayf, im_gray)
print('imread GRAY\t', im_gray.shape)
# imread GRAY    (512, 512)

from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(grayf)
print(', '.join([f'{attr}={getattr(im, attr)}'
                for attr in ('format', 'size', 'mode')]))
# format=JPEG, size=(512, 512), mode=L

img = cv2.imread(grayf, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print('imread COLOR\t', img.shape)
# imread COLOR   (512, 512, 3)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。print(fsrc.shape)で確認したところ(3456, 5184, 3)という結果でした。なぜエラーになっているのか分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: その場合エラーにならないのでは？ `img = rng.integers(256, size=(3456, 5184, 3))`;
`fsrc = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32) / 255`;
`(b, g, r) = cv2.split(fsrc)` であれば普通に動作します

Comment: なぜかエラーになってしまいます、、。他のところで間違いがあるかもしれません。いろいろと教えてくださりありがとうございます。

Comment: この回答の最初のコード「ランダムな画像データを元に再現」(`size=(100,100,2)`の行をコメントアウトしたまま)でエラーは発生しますか？ エラーが発生するようなら cv2のバージョンなど示してみてください

Comment: 確認してみます。ありがとうございます。