# pythonでerror: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'のエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, opencv

pythonで画像を二値化するコードを作成しているのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

エラーは４０行目の`cv2.imwrite(output_dir + img_name, img_th)`の部分で出ているようです。

調べてみると、画像の読み込みができていないみたいなのですが、解決方法がわかりません。
教えてくださる方がおられましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import cv2
import pathlib
import glob
import os
import datetime
import sqlite3
import tqdm 
import numpy as np


input_dir = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/images4' 
output_dir = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/edited/'  

database_name = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/main.db4' 

conn = sqlite3.connect (database_name)
cur = conn. cursor ()
cur. execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item")

cur. execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
     time TEXT, 
     white FLOAT, 
     black FLOAT
)""")

image_list = list(pathlib.Path(input_dir).glob('*.JPG'))

for i in range(len(image_list)):

#画像の読み込み
 img = cv2.imread(str(image_list[i]), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

 ret, img_th = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2. THRESH_BINARY)
 
#画像保存
 img_name = os.path.basename(image_list[i])
 cv2.imwrite(output_dir + img_name, img_th)
  

 cnt_white = cv2. countNonZero (img_th)
 cnt_black = img_th.size - cnt_white
 #print("全体の画素数：" ,img_th.size) 
 print("白の画素数：" ,cnt_white)
 #print("黒の画素数：" ,cnt_black)

 now = datetime.datetime.now()

#データベース
 data = (now, cnt_white, cnt_black)
 cur. execute("INSERT INTO item (time, white, black) values (?, ?, ?)", data)

 conn. commit ()

conn. close ()
```

<追記>
パスの情報についてご指摘頂いたので追記させていただきます。

`print(os.getcwd())`で現在のパスを確認したところ、結果は`/Volumes/Extreme Pro`でした。
また画像フォルダである`input_dir = '/Volumes/Extreme Pro/images4'`の存在を`print(os.path.isdir(input_dir))`で確認したところ、結果は`True`でした。

これらの結果より、パスに関しては合っているということでよろしいのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「画像の読み込みができていないみたいなのですが」であれば、パスが合っているか確認するのがまずやるべきことかと思います。

Comment: パスを確認したところ全て同一のパスとなっていたのすが、間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: @user60891 さん、何のパスを確認して、それらの値は何であったかを質問記事を編集して追記してください。そうした個々の情報を詳細かつ正確に伝えることで助言・回答が得られ易くなるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。パスの情報に関して追記させていただきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

似たようなソースコードのある質問に対して, **確認方法**など記した回答付けてます

- [pythonでnot enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)というエラーが出ます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98264/)

それと同様に(この質問の) **`img_th.shape` などを確認**するようにしてください

同様なエラーは以下のように起こすことが可能

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
img = rng.integers(256, size=(0,0,0))
print(img.shape)

cv2.imwrite('dummy.jpeg', img)
```

```py
(0, 0, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-57f569303384> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 print(img.shape)
      7 
----> 8 cv2.imwrite('dummy.jpeg', img)

error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらのコードに関しましては、画像フォルダをデスクトップに移したところ、解決いたしました。